# GridLayout Support V7 does not enforce column span rules

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-gridlayout, android-appcompat

I've implemented GridLayout V7 into my project properly. When I add it to my XML file, it recognizes it and accepts it, however it does not follow any of the layout rules that I set and all the child views align horizontally.

When I use a regular GridLayout (not the support version) everything works flawlessly.

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.ex.pro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    app:columnCount="3" >

    <TextView

        app:layout_columnSpan="3"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="This should take up the entire row" />

    <TextView
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Row 1, Col 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Row 1, Col 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Row 1, Col 3"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Everything set by `app:` does not work and is completely ignored when I view it in the graphical layout, I don't know what else to try. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change
 `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.ex.pro"`
 for
 `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`